# Problem sending form with id on button and leaving empty fields

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, required

My question is the following and I can not understand where the problem is, I am sending a form with a button that has an id, but the problem is that it can send empty fields, and I need you not to let me send empty fields and in each input I assigned the "required", this only works if I remove the "id" from my button doing that allows me to have no empty fields, but there is the problem because with that id in the button send the information to ajax.

**Code with id in button.**

```
<div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary py-1" style="font-size: 14px" id="btnguardar">Guardar datos</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary py-1" style="font-size: 14px" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

**Code Ajax.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
        var datos=$('#frmpsb').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"insertar.php",
            data:datos,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                }else{
                    alert('Fallo al enviar la peticion.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Removing the id from the code I get what I want, but I could not send my form with ajax anymore.
**Result expect.**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTGIY.png)

Comment: Try `console.log(r);` at the start of `success`.

Comment: It works correctly, the problem is that you can go empty fields and that is what I want to achieve, but if I put an id to my button the fields of my form can go empty ...

And leaving my button without an id now, if you ask me to fill out, I don't know what the problem is that it generates putting an id on my button.

Comment: I can't quite follow. But maybe you want to check that value is non-empty, like this: `$('#frmpsb').find('[name="inputfield1"]).val() != ''` before you send the ajax request.